# Send XMLHttpRequest When User stops writing

Tags: javascript

I Just want to send request when user stops writing... i seem to have stopped extra spam by `(str.length > 3)` this. But What i need is when user stops writing this script gets the input value and send it forward.

This is the updated code right now.

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};


var server = window.location.hostname;
var pathname = window.location.href.split('/');
pathname = (pathname[3]);
var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length === 0) { 
        document.getElementById("search-search"suggest-home").innerHTML = "";
    } if (str.length > 3)  {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               // this.responseText;
                var repox = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var wrapper = document.getElementById("search-search"suggest-home");
                var myhtml = '<ul>';'<ul style="margin-bottom: 0;min-width: 296px;">';
                for (var i = 0; i < repox.length; i++) {
                var repo = repox[i];
                console.log(repo.url);
                if(repo.type == "breakJios12""ios11"){
                myhtml += '<p>'+ repo.2212+'</p>';"<li>";

                }
                if(repo.type == "breakJios11""ios"){
                myhtml += '<p>'+ repo.2213+'</p>';"<li>";
                }
                }
                myhtml += '<li class="ss-bottom" style="padding: 0; border-bottom: none;"><a href="https://'+  server +'/?s='+encodeURIComponent(str).replace('%20','+')+'" id="suggest-all">View all</a></li>';

                wrapper.innerHTML = myhtml;
            }else {
    // Check back again 1 sec later
    setTimeout(checkState, 1000);
  }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://"+ server +"/test/"+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();


    }
}
window.onload = showHint(str);
}, 250);
window.addEventListener('resize', myEfficientFn);
```

**Edit Thanks to @Emiel Zuurbier** Code works now

Comment: I believe that you are looking for a *debounce* function. This is a function which will wait **n** seconds before calling another function. There are a lot of examples on the web. Do some research and make an attempt. If you get stuck, we'll help you out.

Comment: Please add the updated to code your original question above. Keeping all of the questions, answers and code here makes it easier for everyone to help you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great that you've added the debounce function, although it requires some modification. I'll try to explain how you should use it and what happens in your code.

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Create a function which you would use to handle the `onkeyup` event. In your case it is the `showHint` function. Instead of the argument `str` give it the argument `event` which will be the `Event` object created by the `onkeyup` event.

```
function showHint(event) {
    var content = event.target.value;
    // do something with the content
}
```

Now create a *debounced* version of your `showHint` function.
The `debounce` function returns another function which will execute the `showHint` function `250` milliseconds after the user stopped pressing keys. This all has to do with [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
var debounceShowHint = debounce(showHint, 250);
```

Bind the `debounceShowHint` to the `onkeyup` event attribute and give it the `event` parameter which will be passed to your `showHint` function.

```
<input onkeyup="debounceShowHint(event)">
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Your compliments make it worth my while and makes me glad I could help out. Could you revert your code in your question above back to its original state, like you stated your question initially. That way others, and like yourself, with the same question may find an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
function delayRequest()
{
   var timer=0;
   function callbackfunc(callback, ms)
   {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer=setTimeout(callback, ms);
   }
   return callbackfunc;
}

var delay=(delayRequest)();

$('#search-suggest-home').on("keyup cut paste", function (e)
{
   delay(function (){ return your_ajax_call_func();  }, delay_time);
});
```

You can set value of `delay_time` in milliseconds. The time after which you want to send ajax request, when user stops writing.

In last statement I have used jQuery!!